# I want to add an foreign key but everytime i try adding one i get error codes

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Coding that i used to altar my table and change it.

```
ALTER TABLE `the-challenge`.`klant` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `resultaat`
  FOREIGN KEY (`resultaatid`)
  REFERENCES `the-challenge`.`resultaat` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

The results when trying to apply the code:
Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:

```
ALTER TABLE `the-challenge`.`klant` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `resultaat`
  FOREIGN KEY (`resultaatid`)
  REFERENCES `the-challenge`.`resultaat` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

> ERROR 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'resultaat'

SQL Statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `the-challenge`.`klant` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `resultaat`
  FOREIGN KEY (`resultaatid`)
  REFERENCES `the-challenge`.`resultaat` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Avoid the use of backticks when not needed. They make the code more difficult to read.

Comment: Seems like the constraint `resultaat` was already defined before. Maybe you need to drop it before trying to add it again.

Comment: Constraint name must be unique within the schema (database). *ERROR 1826: Duplicate foreign key constraint name 'resultaat'* This means that some constraint in your database (in another table, for example) is assigned with this name. Check INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS. It is recommended to use the tablename as a prefix of the constraint name.

Comment: so turns out there was another foreign with the same information so i dropped it and tried to give my foreign key name a different name but maintaining the same concept and i got a different error code:

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`the-challenge`.`#sql-13c8_5c`, CONSTRAINT `result` FOREIGN KEY (`resultaatid`)

Comment: This means that the data already present in tables contradicts your FK. Check the data and edit it (add needed values to `resultaat` table or remove excess rows from `klant`  table).